# Validate record component value during construction with a custom annotation

Tags: java, record, micronaut

I try to validate the components of a record using a custom annotation so that creating a new record object fails if the value is invalid.

Using Micronaut v3.8.6 and Java 19 (preview features activated), having defined a sealed interface

```
@Introspected
public sealed interface UserId {
    record Identifier(@Positive long value) implements UserId {}
    record MailAddress(@EMail String value) implements UserId {}
}
```

using this annotation

```
@Target({PARAMETER, RECORD_COMPONENT, TYPE_USE, CONSTRUCTOR, FIELD, METHOD, ANNOTATION_TYPE})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Constraint(validatedBy = {})
public @interface EMail {

    String message() default "is not a valid email address: ({validatedValue})";
}
```

putting all together with the factory

```
@Factory
public class AppConfig {
    @Singleton
    public ConstraintValidator<EMail, String> eMailStringConstraintValidator() {
        return (value, annotationMetadata, context) -> EMailAddressConstraints.isValid(value);
    }
}
```

where the `isValid` method just returns a boolean but no exception to be thrown.

The validator is never called when creating a new MailAddress object. To make sure it basically works, I've annotated a parameter of a controller method. Passing an invalid string fails as expected.

Why is the annotation ignored when creating the record? Btw I tried to get it to work with declaring the canonical constructor with annotated parameters explicitly too ...

Comment: Do you call `validator.validate(obj)` method on that object after it is created? Validation does not happen automatically when you create a new instance of the object, you have to pass it to a specific validator that will perform validation. This blog post explains it pretty well - https://markoantic.medium.com/conditional-validation-in-java-applications-80a24f06d721

Comment: No, I don't call any method. When annotating a parameter of a controller method, the validation is done without calling any validation method. I don't want the record object to be created if the component is invalid.

Comment: When you annotate a controller method parameter, this is exactly what happens - the object is created and then it's passed to a validator to check if its current state matches all validation constraints. The same thing happens if you annotated e.g. a service method parameter, but again - it will create an object and then validate it before the method invocation happens. There's not such thing as validating an object's constraints on a constructor call without the presence of a validator context.